# C# get every n-th element with WHERE, strange result

Tags: c#, linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) list.Add(i);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", list.Where((o, i) => i % 4 == 0).Select((o, i) => i).ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Can someone explain, why code above returns 0 1 2 3 instead of 0 4 8 12?

Comment: You would get the index either by selecting the value or if you'd store them in an anonymous type **before** the `Where`. Because afterwards you don't see the original indices but the ones of the filtered sequence..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are selecting the index instead the value. Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", list.Where(o =>o % 4 == 0).Select((o, i) => o).ToArray()));
```

If you are not going to do nothing with the index then do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", list.Where(o => o % 4 == 0).ToArray()));
```

Comment: Ok, now realized "i" in where and in select are different.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct anonymous type first to *remember* index:

```
list.Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index})
    .Where(o => o.Index % 4 == 0)
    .Select(o => $"Item {o.Item} at index {o.Index}");
```